# Whats going on in my kali linux? E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. Im a Newbie

Tags: kali-linux, apt, packages, dependencies, linebreaks

I was installing this package when this happened.

```
root@kali:~/airgeddon# apt install isc-dhcp-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: mutter (< 3.31.4) but 3.30.2-7 is to be installed
 linux-headers-4.19.0-kali4-amd64 : Depends: linux-compiler-gcc-8-x86 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

How TO Fix All This Mess?

Comment: And Kali might be the worst OS for a newbie. This error can be caused by an incomplete package installation.

Comment: You might try updating your Kali Kernel. My kernel is at 5.8.0 for Kali V20202.4  (.3 for 4 or 5 months and .4 this week). Then use sudo apt-get to do a full update and upgrade.

Comment: ok, i received the message....I should say bye to kali...thats ok!

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: Add the output from `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply clear the dpkg/status as follows...

> leafpad /var/lib/dpkg/status

Select all [Ctrl+A], and delete (Del)

Make sure the status is cleared by typing...

> cat /var/lib/dpkg/status

Update apt and install failed packages...

> apt update
> apt install -f

[image]

Now install the DHCP server...

> sudo apt install -y isc-dhcp-server